# Kendo grid read action method not fire

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid

```
<div id="grid"></div>
(document).ready(function () {
    var dataSourceA = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: "../Test/CourseRead",
            dataType: "json"
        }
    });
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSourceA,
        height: 550,
        groupable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },
        columns: [{
            field: "CourseName",
            title: "Course Name",
            width: 240
        }]
    });
});
 public ActionResult CourseRead([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        IQueryable<CourseInformationMasterViewModel> course = (from m in db.CourseInformationMasters
                                                               select new CourseInformationMasterViewModel{
                                                               CourseName=m.CourseName,
                                                               CourseCode=m.CourseCode,
                                                               CourseCredit=m.CourseCredit,
                                                               MasterCourseId=m.MasterCourseId
                                                               });
        DataSourceResult result = course.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(result);
    }
```

My action methos name is CourseRead and controller name is Test.action method is firing but display a empty grid.json result return value i chechk this.but the grid is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got my answer.i make mistake in my action method.update action method is:

```
 public JsonResult CourseRead()
    {
        var course = (from m in db.CourseInformationMasters
                      select new CourseInformationMasterViewModel
                      {
                          CourseName = m.CourseName,
                          CourseCode = m.CourseCode,
                          MasterCourseId = m.MasterCourseId
                      });
        return Json(course, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its seem like your making get request, By default jsonResult doest

When you need to allowget or use get ,we have to use JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet.

```
 public ActionResult CourseRead([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
..
 return Json(new Modle.JsonResponseData { result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
..
}
```

Make sure that `read: "../Test/CourseRead"` call your controller action else you may use view engine to call ur action from view..